# Secure HTTPS request fails 90% of the time

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, networking

I'm using a NodeMCU, which is connected to an enterprise network at a school. The information given in the GET requests that the ESP8266 sends is sensitive, so naturally we want to make it secure and encrypted - enter SSL. We do the request like so;

`HTTPClient http.begin(url, thumbprint)`

However, on the network at the school, doing this request fails 90% of the time, so I did a few tests - 100 requests to the exact same IP and certificate, noting how many went through;

- **School network**

  - HTTP**S** requests: 10/100 successful **[10%]**
  - HTTP requests: 100/100 successful **[100%]**
- **Private home network**

  - HTTP**S** requests: 100/100 successful **[100%]**
  - HTTP requests: 100/100 successful **[100%]**

We have also tried using the `WiFiClient` class, and while 100% of the requests went through, each one took 15 seconds which is too long.

My question is; what would the problem be, and what can we do to fix it? Can I do something in the code, or on the network?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @Gerben No stack errors, the response contains nothing and the HTTP code is -11

Comment: Your school probably uses a proxy which tries to filter out phishing sites or something. It's possible that it only works fast for white-listed domains.

Comment: I asked about this, and they told me there was nothing blocking my site. Again, it works 10% of the time. They said there was no firewall...

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout (HTTPClient.setTimeout) until you get 100% success?

Comment: @Craig didn't think of this! The requests actually go through 100% of the time now (at a 100000 timeout, just for now), so that's great! Although each request takes about 4.5 seconds compared to the 300ms that the unsecure requests take. But I'll take it! Post it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: As to why there is a difference between the 2 networks I'm not sure. I would turn up the log level on your server and see if that points you toward the problem.

Comment: you should consider an ESP32 if you need to make fast HTTPS requests from an MCU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the timeout for your request with `HTTPClient.setTimeout()`. Note the timeout is in milliseconds.

```
HTTPClient http;
http.setTimeout(15000); // 15 Seconds
http.begin(url, thumbprint);
```